# AudioComponentCount not finding AUs

Tags: macos, xcode4.3, audiounit

I'm trying to update a simple sequencer I wrote a few years ago in XCode 3. I hit a brick wall at the very outset because AudioComponentCount and AudioComponentFindNext do not find my software instruments.
They just find two: Apple's DLS music device and their sampler.

I have several others which I can see in the library Components file. Auval sees them too, and passes them OK. They also work fine with my old sequencer, where they are found OK by the same functions. And I have checked that the components are up to date.

I do have the AudioUnits framework linked in (and the program compiles OK, it just doesn't do the right thing). Trying CountComponents with the CoreServices famework gives the same problem.

All the Apple documentation and sample code I have found indicates that my code should work.

Can someone suggest why these functions should be blind to perfectly good synths?

(I am compiling using XCode 4.3.3 on a Mac Quad-core Intel Xeon running Mac OS X 10.7.5. Could it be incompatibility between the up-to-date XCode and the Lion OS??)